# My function has an argument of type chartpainteventargs. How can I call this function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, 3d

```
chart1_PostPaint(Chart chart, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
```

In above function, ChartPaintEventArgs is used. I want to call this function. But I don't know how to define a ChartPaintEventArgs. I've tried defining it. But I get error that no constructor is defined. Can anyone help.

Comment: Why are you trying to call it? If another method beyond this event handler needs to run some shared code, it would probably be better to move that shared code into its own method instead of manually calling an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.postpaint?view=netframework-4.7.2, postPaint Occurs after chart element was drawn. This event is raised for elements such as ChartArea and Legend

As per doc, I hope you have to just override the event if needed. You need not call it.